# What is the origin of the shift of meaning of "sauté"?

Tags: terminology, homonyms

As I'm dealing a lot of recipes and text on cooking written in English, I'm confronted all the time with a trend which makes understanding quite hard sometimes.

The original French word "sauté" has a very specific meaning. It requires very high heat, so high that the vegetable pieces would scorch if left for more than a few seconds on the pan - so they are continuously moved around in a "jumping" motion. This is the meaning which is used in cooking textbooks like [The professional chef](http://www.amazon.de/Professional-Chef-Culinary-Institute-America/dp/0470421355/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420490564&sr=8-1&keywords=the%20professional%20chef), and also in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saut%C3%A9ing) article. This is what cooking professionals are taught, and what they think about, when they see the word.

There are tons of recipes published in popular media which start with "sauté the onions". From a culinary point of view, "sauté" (in its professional meaning) would be the wrong thing to do, or at least suboptimal. But from my observation, nobody is doing it anyway. What they are doing is "shallow frying" the onions, with other, more specific words, also applicable in some cases, such as "sweating" and "caramelizing".

By now, I have seen such prevalence of the term, that I think it's fair to say that it can be considered a second meaning. We have the worst sort of polysemy: the same word is used by two groups (but confusingly in the same domain) with two conflicting meanings.

Can anybody shed some information on when this trend started, and is there known evidence for the reasons why it started at all?

Comment: "homonyms" are words that happen to be spelled or pronounced the same by chance, but are otherwise unrelated. That's hardly the case here. Obviously the new meaning is derived from the old, perhaps as a result of misunderstanding or normal language drift.

Comment: This is called 'broadening'. From [english--language.weebly.com](http://english--language.weebly.com/semantic-changes.html):
Broadening is the change in the meaning of a word by expansion, so that the word is applicable in more contexts than it previously was and means more than it previously did.

An example of broadening is the word "business", which originally meant "a state of being busy, careworn or anxious", but has now broadened to include all kinds of work occupations. // This can be useful, but, as with the case you point out, can be undesirable, blurring important distinctions.

Comment: @barmar feel free to edit my text for proper usage of linguistic terms. I have only ever learned the "same word, different meaning" definition of "homonym" without hearing the "unrelated" part mentioned - maybe this is a parallel case where the commonly known meaning of "homonym" is different between laypeople and professional linguists.

Comment: @rumtscho Well, I think your whole premise that these are mutual exclusive is misguided. The common use is just a variation on the original definition. It's not like the new meaning refers to baking, a completely different process. They're just different forms of frying.

Comment: A recipe that says to sauté the onions by getting the pan medium-hot, adding a small amount of oil, then adding the onions, constantly keeping them moving to avoid burning the onions -- how is that **not** sautéing? A better example of misuse of the word "sauté" is so-called sautéd fish. What those recipes describe is pan-fried fish. Ymmm. Sautéd fish? Those two words don't go together.

Comment: @barmar of course they are both forms of frying, but they have different results and are therefore used in different circumstances. It is comparable to the relation of "paint the wall" and "spray grafitti on the wall". Imagine that you start reading DIY books which say "1. Erect the drywall, 2. Prime the surface, 3. Paint grafitti on the wall" in an article explaining how to make a wall with even coloring, and lists "dispersion paint and roller" as the materials needed.

Comment: @DavidHammen your recipe describes the original meaning of sautéing, although "medium hot" is ambiguous, they wouldn't burn at what I normally consider "medium hot". But in many recipes, the onions should be put on a heat so low that they won't burn, and then left undisturbed for quite a long time (at least 10 minutes if you want them light). This is not "sauté" in its original meaning, but it is how many people do it (in fact, heat high enough to require constant stirring will burn the coating right off the PTFE pans they are using), and they still call it sauté.

Comment: A recipe that calls for sautéing and says to check the temperature of the pan by seeing if a drop of water placed on the pan does its neat little dance (the Leidenfrost effect) -- that's sautéing. A recipe that calls for sautéing that also calls for covering the pan -- okay, that's not sautéing/ (And yes, I've seen those recipes.) So? Some people misuse words. It doesn't necessarily mean there's been a word shift. It just means some people are dumb.

Comment: @David Hammen Ignorant people cause a lot of word shifts. When (as here) misunderstandings can arise, it is senseless to assume the earlier meaning / the meaning with the better pedigree (oh, I use 'strychnine' to mean 'saccharine'). On the other hand, terminology should be clarified at the start of a book, lecture, article etc.

Comment: I've addressed the linguistics terminology. // There are many other examples of conflicting senses of a word causing confusion and argument. Even 'word', 'sentence', 'clause' and 'scalarity' are used inconsistently.

Answer (score 5):

***[sauté](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/saut%C3%A9)***

> VERB (*sautés*, *sautéing*, *sautéed* or *sautéd*)
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Fry quickly in a little hot fat:
>
> *> He sautéed the onions in olive oil.*
>
> NOUN
>
> 2. Ballet A jump off both feet, landing in the same position.

The professional [***culinary***](http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/dryheatcooking/a/sauteing.htm) use of the word is true to the image of the etymology:

> 1813, from French *sauté*, literally "*jumped, bounced*" (in reference to
>   tossing continually while cooking),
>
> past participle of *sauter* "*to jump*,"
>
> from Latin *saltare* "*to hop, dance*," frequentative of *salire* "*to leap*"
>   (see salient (adj.)).
>
> As an adjective, "*fried quickly*," from 1869. As a verb from 1859.

The etymology does concede *fry quickly* as a meaning from 1869, so the culinary nuances of *fry quickly* seem to be under consideration. The 1851 publication, *[Frank Forester's Fish and Fishing of the United States and ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=hVUMAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA339&dq=%22saute%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ChqrVNznK8L_yQTzwoGoAw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBTgo#v=onepage&q=%22saute%22&f=false)* offers a theoretical point of departure:

> Scale and well dry six Pearches, and make incisions here and there on
>   each side of them ; then put a quarter of a pound of butter into a
>   sauté-pan, season your fishes with pepper and salt, put them in the
>   sauté pan and ***fry them gently***, turning...

This is no iron-clad explanation, but if people were routinely instructed to use a ***sauté***-pan to fry things ***gently*** in a quarter pound of butter, it would be a matter of time before this *frying gently* became associated with the word *sauté*.

In 1879, it seems confusion was again articulated in ***[Cooley's Cyclopædia of Practical Receipts](https://books.google.com/books?id=9oU6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA765&dq=%22saut%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sh6rVKDQJYOjyQTqrYDoCw&ved=0CDQQ6wEwBDha#v=onepage&q=%22saut%C3%A9%22&f=false)***

> According to the (common) mode in which all objects are cooked which
>   are called fried, it would answer to the French word '***sauté***,' or the
>   old English term '***frizzled***' but to fry any object, it should be to
>   ***immersed in very hot fat***, oil, or butter...

Comparing *sauté* to ***[frizzle](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/frizzle)***:

> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> 1. Fry or grill with a sizzling noise:
>
>    [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1.1 Fry until crisp, shriveled, or burnt:

Since the common use has broadened so far, it might be appropriate to consider the narrower definition of *sauté* to be part of a *professional dialect*.